# Add custom meta data into emails as a html styled table with a title in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, *"[Get a custom field array values within WooCommerce email order meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274892/get-a-custom-field-array-values-within-woocommerce-email-order-meta/50278815#50278815)"* answer code to one of my previous questions, has given me the way to pull fields out of an array from the order post meta data.

But how would I take this code and adjust it, to add a heading above the new data and a table around the data, within the email?

1. I would like to add a `<h2>Attendee Info</h2>` above the output of the fields. In addition I'd like to wrap the field output in a `<table>`.
2. I would like to add a few of the fields as new columns within the admin Order Table screen, via some sort of function.

In addition, I would also like to be able to display some of these fields within the Admin Order Table, as new columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using instead `woocommerce_email_order_details`  action hook this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_after_email_order_details', 25, 4 );
function action_after_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )
{
    $event = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'WooCommerceEventsOrderTickets', true );

    if( ! is_array($event) ) return;

    $event = isset($event[1][1]) ? $event[1][1] : '';

    if( sizeof($event) == 0 ) return;

    $custom = isset($event['WooCommerceEventsCustomAttendeeFields']) ? $event['WooCommerceEventsCustomAttendeeFields'] : '';

    // Set our array of needed data
    $fields_array = [
        __('First name')    => isset($event['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeName']) ? $event['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeName'] : '',
        __('Last name')     => isset($event['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeLastName']) ? $event['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeLastName'] : '',
        __('Title')         => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_title']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_title'] : '',
        __('Organization')  => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_organization']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_organization'] : '',
        __('Address')       => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_address']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_address'] : '',
        __('City')          => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_city']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_city'] : '',
        __('Postcode')      => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_postal_code']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_postal_code'] : '',
        __('State')         => isset($custom['fooevents_custom_state/province']) ? $custom['fooevents_custom_state/province'] : '',
    ];

    if( ! $event ) return;

    // The HTML Structure
    $html_output = '<h2>' . __('Attendee Info') . '</h2>
    <div class="discount-info">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6"><tbody>';

    // Loop though the data array to set the fields
    foreach( $fields_array as $label => $value ):
    if( ! empty($value) ):

    $html_output .= '<tr>
        <th>' . $label . '</th>
        <td>' . $value . '</td>
    </tr>';

    endif;
    endforeach;

    $html_output .= '</tbody></table>
    </div><br>'; // HTML (end)

    // The CSS styling
    $styles = '<style>
        .discount-info table{width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; margin-bottom:8px;}
        .discount-info table th, table.tracking-info td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px; width:58%;}
        .discount-info table td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;}
    </style>';

    // The Output CSS + HTML
    echo $styles . $html_output;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

or also using `woocommerce_email_order_meta` action hook, replacing the first line:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_after_email_order_details', 25, 4 );
```

by this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 25, 4 );
```

---

You will get something more clean and formatted with your title like:

[image]

> To get this data displayed in admin order table is something much more complicate and too broad to be answer in this answer or on stackOverFlow.
>
> You should better display that data in a custom meta box in order edit pages, which is much more easier and practical.

Comment: That seems to work well. The only issue I see is that the "Attendee Info" title and table wrapper still show up, even if the product doesn't have those fields.

Comment: I added if statements to your wrapper code, and it seems to work well for my needs now. Thanks!

Comment: any idea how to update this, in case there are numerous arrays within the array? Ideally, it would spit out a table for each one: https://d.pr/free/n/nKHS0H

Comment: Any idea how to format this to display : 
`Attendee 1 - FirstName(value) LastName(value)`
each on a separate row?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This doesn't work with multiple attendees, it only shows the info for the 1st one???

Comment: @darko This answer doesn't handle multiple attendees, just one.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec OK, I will repost the question than to include the multiple attendees info