# Add some meta data values in a clean table for new order emails in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, email-notifications

In the function file, I created the code. Task: add order data to the email alert.
There is no registration on the site.
I want to do this as a table with tittle. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280473/add-custom-meta-data-into-emails-as-a-html-styled-table-with-a-title-in-woocomme#_=_). But in it all the data is taken from the module's metadata. And I have metadata and default information together.
Not need to write all html. Just push me in the right direction how correct write my data.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['billing_first_name'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Name' ),
        'value' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
    );

    $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Phone' ),
        'value' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
    );

    $fields['billing_address_1'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Street' ),
        'value' => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
    );

    $fields['billing_address_2'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Build' ),
        'value' => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
    );

    $fields['billing_address_3'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Apartment' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Apartment', true ),
    );

    $fields['billing_address_4'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Floor' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Floor', true ),
    );

    $fields['billing_address_5'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Entrance' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Entrance', true ),
    );

    $fields['customer_message'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Note' ),
        'value' => $order->customer_message,
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** In your code replace outdated `$order->id` by `$order->get_id()` everywhere.

To add custom fields meta data with default order meta data in a clean html , try this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_after_email_order_details', 25, 4 );
function action_after_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )
{
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    // Define all translatable custom fields labels and data
    $fields_array = [
        [ 'label' => __( 'Name', $domain ),      'value' => $order->get_billing_first_name() ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Phone', $domain ),     'value' => $order->get_billing_phone() ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Street', $domain ),    'value' => $order->get_billing_address_1() ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Build', $domain ),     'value' => $order->get_billing_address_2() ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Apartment', $domain ), 'value' => $order->get_meta( 'Apartment', true ) ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Floor', $domain ),     'value' => $order->get_meta( 'Floor', true ) ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Entrance', $domain ),  'value' => $order->get_meta( 'Entrance', true ) ],
        [ 'label' => __( 'Note', $domain ),      'value' => $order->get_customer_note() ],
    ];

    // The HTML Structure
    $html_output = '<h2>' . __( 'Extra data (title)', $domain ) . '</h2>
    <div class="discount-info">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6"><tbody>';

    // Loop though the data array to set the fields
    foreach( $fields_array as $field ):

    // Only display non empty fields values
    if( ! empty($field['value']) ):

    $html_output .= '<tr>
        <th>' . $field['label'] . ':</th>
        <td>' . $field['value'] . '</td>
    </tr>';

    endif;
    endforeach;

    $html_output .= '</tbody></table>
    </div><br>'; // HTML (end)

    // The CSS styling
    $styles = '<style>
        .discount-info table{width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; margin-bottom:8px;}
        .discount-info table th, table.tracking-info td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;}
        .discount-info table td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;}
    </style>';

    // The Output CSS + HTML
    echo $styles . $html_output;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> To target the "New Order" email notification only, you can add the following line inside the function code at the beginning:

```
if ( $email->id !== 'new_order' ) return;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best!